# Size Tkinter Text Widget by Pixels - Text Truncated

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm a beginner with tkinter and would appreciate some help with the following code. I can't understand why the text in the left hand frame is truncated - it seems to imply the frame is larger than is being displayed. How do I make it wrap within the displayed area?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class Display:

    def __init__(self, master):
        app = Frame(master)
        app.grid()

        self.l_frame = Frame(app,width=200, height=500)
        self.r_frame = Frame(app,width=500, height=500)
        self.r_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.l_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.l_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.r_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

        self.mono_font = tkFont.Font(family="monospace",size=24,weight="bold")
        self.instructions = "A longish string of text which I want to display using Tkinter but for some reason gets truncated"

        self.info = Text(self.l_frame, wrap=WORD, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5)
        self.info.insert(1.0,self.instructions)
        self.info.grid()

        self.island = Text(self.r_frame, bg="cyan", padx=20, pady=20, font=self.mono_font)
        self.island.insert(1.0, "ready")
        self.island.grid()

root = Tk()
game = Display(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is it you're really trying to accomplish? Turning geometry propagation off is almost never the right solution. Is it really important that the left area is exactly 200 pixels? Why not specify it in a number of characters?

Comment: It's for a text-based game, and I figured with different size fonts things could get confusing. Also, as a learning exercise, I'd like to achieve what I set out to do, even if it's not the best approach.

Comment: font changes is exactly why you should let tkinter do all the math. If the user has bigger fonts, you probably want the window to grow automatically.

Comment: But if I have one font size for the left textbox and a different one for the right, doesn't that mean a lot of trial and error to get the layout I want, rather than deciding in advance what size I want the overall window to be? Maybe that's how these thing are usually done. I'm still curious why the text doesn't simply wrap within the frame.

Comment: No trial and error. Decide how big you want the GUI based on characters, not pixel sizes. That's generally a much more user-friendly way to design a UI. Completely forget about setting a window size. Set the size of the components, and let tkinter create an optimal size based on the font size and screen resolution. If you're using rows or columns you can specify proportions rather than fixed sizes.

Comment: Ok thanks. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the .grid method in tkinter, but I managed to do what I think you're looking for using the Label option and some .grid positioning.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class Display:

    def __init__(self, master):
        app = Frame(master)
        app.grid()

        self.l_frame = Frame(app,width=200, height=500)
        self.r_frame = Frame(app,width=500, height=500)
        self.r_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.l_frame.grid_propagate(False)
        self.l_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.r_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)

        self.mono_font = tkFont.Font(family="monospace",size=24,weight="bold")
        self.instructions = Label(root, wraplength=195, text="A longish string of text which I want to display using Tkinter but for some reason gets truncated") # Made this a label with wraplength

        self.info = Text(self.l_frame, wrap=WORD, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5)
        #self.info.insert(1.0,self.instructions) #Commented this out, didn't seem to need it.
        self.instructions.grid(row=0, sticky=NW)

        self.island = Text(self.r_frame, bg="cyan", padx=20, pady=20, font=self.mono_font)
        self.island.insert(1.0, "ready")
        self.island.grid()

root = Tk()
game = Display(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, as a beginner, in order to feel less daunted, I'd like to know that I can do something as seemingly simple as create a frame with 2 horizontal text boxes of pre-determined size. Taming the beast, as it were...

Comment: From what I"ve read about the Frame widgets is that they aren't typically used for text, but rather just to help organize and arrange other widgets. "Frame widgets are used to group other widgets into complex layouts. They are also used for padding, and as a base class when implementing compound widgets." - from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm